# ARC issue with static objects in memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I just realized a small problem in memory allocation, and releasing unnecessary instances.

So I have a view controller with two dispatch queues.

```
static dispatch_queue_t _queue_1;
static dispatch_queue_t _queue_2;

@interface
...
@end
```

!! The view controller never gets deallocated.

However if they are not static, and part of that view controller class, `dealloc` gets called.

```
dispatch_queue_t _queue_1;
dispatch_queue_t _queue_2;
```

This bugs me because I didn't think static variables would bump up it's retain count? I mean - it exists throughout the app-life-cycle as a static variable. But why is this tied up with that VC class? Why is the VC not getting deallocated in the first test?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more context and useful info. There's far too little to go on at this point to help you.

Comment: In what class does the code in your example exist? If you're showing that little code, you need to explain the context.

Answer (score 1):

One or more of the blocks of code that you are dispatching to those queues contains a strong reference to the view controller. This causes a reference cycle and as a result your view controller is never getting deallocated.

Comment: Yes, didn't think of this possibility. Thanks for the hint.